# Який український аналог технічного терміну "cookie"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

> Cookie — у комп'ютерній термінології поняття, яке використовується для
>   опису інформації у вигляді текстових або бінарних даних, отриманих від
>   веб-сайту на веб-сервері, яка зберігається у клієнта, тобто браузера,
>   а потім відправлена на той же сайт, якщо сайт повторно відвідати.
>   [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Дослівний переклад "cookie" — "тістечко", "печиво", що, очевидно, не може використовуватись в якості технічного терміну.

Також зустрічав у вжитку варіанти "ку́ки", "ку́кі" і "реп'яшки", проте, суб'єктивно, ці варіанти не є оптимальними і не відображають суть терміну.

Чи є інші варіанти перекладу?

Comment: "реп'яшки" ще й як відображають суть терміну))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Варіант "реп'яшки" використовується наразі у Facebook:

[image: частковий скриншот сторінки в соціальній мережі Facebook]

На користь цього варіанту зазвичай наводиться аргумент, що ці файли "причіпляються" до клієнта й залишаються з ним, так само, як це відбувається із реп'яхами.

Також часто зустрічається варіант "файли cookie".

Comment: Також спільнота [Словотвору](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kuky) вважає для cookies найкращим перекладом слово _реп'яшки_.

Answer (score 8):

Не очевидно, чому `печиво` не може використовуватись в якості технічного терміну. `cookie` не має інших значень в англійській, тому в англійській мові воно і звучить як кулінарний виріб, а не як спеціальний термін, і не пояснюють суть.

Можливо, в англійській культурі до комп'ютерних технологій ставляться не так серйозно, як в СРСР, де непосвяченим людям наукові терміни здаються справді загадковими (чого варте одне таємниче `ЕОМ` — `електронно-обчислювальна машина`, порівняйте з `computer` — `той, що рахує`). Тому в нашій країні спадщина радянських часів змушує ставитись до перекладу `печиво` зневажливо — звучить "ненауково".

Answer (score 5):

Якщо подивитися [історію](https://www.reference.com/technology/computer-cookies-called-cookies-f0e2d0e3a1d78f14) цього терміну, то ми побачимо наступне:

> Computer cookies were so named by the original developer of this
>   technology, Lou Montulli, as an homage to an earlier piece of computer
>   monitoring technology known as "magic cookies." This earlier
>   technology performed a function similar to modern cookies. They
>   transmitted short code segments between machines for identification.
>   Montulli developed the modern cookie in 1994 while working for the
>   Internet company Netscape

Тобто, вони отримали назву, скоріше за все, від печива з передбаченнями. Тому "печивом" чи "коржиками" називати не так грішно, але "куки", ймовірно, вимовляти швидше.

Answer (score 1):

Я песиміст, тому див. мій песимістичний коментар, який чомусь видалили: жоден запропонований раніше варіант, як і жоден запропонований в майбутньому, не може бути істиною в останній інстанції — відколи я відкрив для себе інтернет, маю змогу спостерігати, як проти будь-якої української назви для цього поняття збирається спільнота супротивників, що методично його топлять, пропонуючи якийсь інший варіант, тож пошук вдалого слова для cookies давно став нескінченною грою в обламайку.
Наприклад:
Є слово «кукіси» — але ж варваризм, замінімо на щось українське, наприклад, «коржики».
Є слово «коржики» — але ж буквальний переклад, замінімо на щось ближче до оригіналу, наприклад, «куки».
Є слово «куки» — але ж фе як гидко звучить, замінімо на щось оригінальне, наприклад, «реп'яшки».
Є слово «реп'яшки» — але ж як далеко від оригіналу! Замінімо на…

Причина одна: ми живемо поза середовищем, де дані, що зберігаються на стороні веб-клієнта, назвали cookies (букв. коржики, печиво). Може, це якась усталена традиція давати гостям на дорогу печиво? Або ж це частина якоїсь історії, де один з учасників проекту приходив у гості з печивом, яке потім йому давали на дорогу, і він приносив його назад? Або це щось узагалі непов'язане з печивом/коржиками — просто співзвучне в англійській?..

Коротше, доки ми не знаємо достеменно, чому їх назвали саме cookies, а не cakes, lollipops, flowers, cows, butterflies чи ще якось, доти будь-який осмислений переклад неможливий. Особисто мене влаштували б або «коржики» (буквальний переклад), або «кукіси» (пряме запозичення, максимально близьке до cookies), або будь-який варіант, широко вживаний протягом достатньо довгого проміжку часу — проте, проти будь-якого варіанту завжди є «вагомі» аргументи, тому усталеної української назви об'єктивно нема, кожне нове слово висмикують з ґрунту раніше, ніж воно встигає вкоренитись, замінюючи його «чимось кращим», на яке чекає така ж доля. Хіба що, найбільш очевидні варіанти (прме запозичення, буквальний переклад) мають дещо вищі шанси повернутися в майбутньому й нарешті вкоренитися. Утім, не факт, що до того часу технологія cookies чи навіть увесь http не застаріє.

Comment: Пробачте, але -1. Ця відповідь відповідає формату блоґів чи соцмереж, вона запрошує до дискусії і викладає деякі слушні думки. **Але.** На StackExchange ми віддаємо перевагу відповідям, які, власне, відповідають на запитання, ґрунтуючись на наукових знаннях. Власна думка автора може підсилювати аргументацію, але не бути основною. Окрім того, на жаль, 2 із 3 абзаців цієї відповіді ґрунтуються на незнанні, а не на знаннях. *Cookies* походить від *fortune cookies* — це типово американське явище, і саме це є причиною складнощів перекладу.

Comment: Ну а як іще сказати, що виробленої норми поки що нема?! Питання правильне, потрібне, важливе — видаляти його не слід, але правильна відповідь коротко звучатиме так: усталена норма не виробилась, і нема ознак, що нинішні фейсбучні «реп'яшки» розповсюдяться й проживуть довше, ніж «коржики», що в середині нульових також були присутні в різних локалізаціях ПЗ.

Comment: @bytebuster Будь ласка, не використовуйте напів відповіді у коментарях. ))))

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, мені здалося, що ви переплутали. Мій коментар написаний під відповіддю і призначений для покращення цієї відповіді. Коли писалася [стаття](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/222/8) про «напіввідповіді у коментарях» — там йшлося про коментарі під запитанням.